# How I validate a array of object inside a Object in request body with express validator

Tags: javascript, express-validator

Request Body is like

```
{
  "name":"nazmul Haque",
  "age" : "26",
   "favoriteBooks" :
                      [ 
                        { 
                            "name": "A Murder is announced",
                            "writer":"Agatha Christie",
                            "price"  :700 
                         },
                        {
                            "name": "Srikanto",
                            "writer":"Sarat Chandra Chattopadhyay",
                            "price"  :500
                        }
                     ]
                    
}
```

Now I want to validate `name` key exists or not and the length must be in 256 and `price` can not be empty of every object of the favorite books. and how I do that with express validator without custom method.

like if our req body will look like in below

```
                [ 
                        { 
                            "name": "A Murder is announced",
                            "writer":"Agatha Christie",
                            "price"  :700 
                         },
                        {
                            "name": "Srikanto",
                            "writer":"Sarat Chandra Chattopadhyay",
                            "price"  :500
                        }
                     ]
```

than we can validate it like

```
body().isArray().withMessage("body is not an array"),
  body("*.name", "name can not be null").exists().notEmpty().isLength({max:256}),
  body("*.price")
    .exists()
    .notEmpty()
    .withMessage("price can not be null"),
```

I can not do it with the process in above For `1st Req Body` because there `array of Object` inside of a `object`

Answer (score 1):

```js
export const complexValidation = [
    body('name', "Name must be a string")
        .isLength({ min: 1 }),
    body('age', "age must be a integer")
        .isInt(),
    body('favoriteBooks', "favoriteBooks must be an array with min single value")
        .isArray({ min: 1 }),
    body('favoriteBooks.*.name', "Name must be a string")
        .isLength({ min: 1 }),
    body('favoriteBooks.*.writer', "Name must be a string")
        .isLength({ min: 1 }),
    body('favoriteBooks.*.price', "Name must be a string")
        .isNumeric()
]
```